# how to parse commit message into variables using bash?

Tags: regex, bash, string-parsing

I using bash and I have string (a commit message)

```
:sparkles: feat(xxx): this is a commit
```

and I want to divide it into variables sections:

```
emoji=:sparkles:
type=feat
scope=xxx
message=this is a commit
```

I try to use grep, but the regex is not return what I need (for example the "type") and anyway how to paste it into variables?

```
echo ":sparkles: feat(xxx): this is a commit" | grep "[((.*))]"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With bash version >= 3, a regex and an array:

```
x=":sparkles: feat(xxx): this is a commit"

[[ "$x" =~ ^(:.*:)\ (.*)\((.*)\):\ (.*)$ ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
```

Output:

```
:sparkles:
feat
xxx
this is a commit
```

From `man bash`:

> `BASH_REMATCH`: An  array  variable  whose members are assigned by the =~ binary operator to the [[ conditional command.  The element
>                 with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element with index  n  is  the
>                 portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.  This variable is read-only.